# javascript splitting a var that is numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd prefer to not use regex, but if needed, so be it.

I have some code and I want to take a user's input and check to make sure that it is an isbn 10. In other words it must be a 10 digit number or a 9 digit number with an x at the end (the x represents the number 10). For my purposes, I'd like to turn the users input into an array of each digit. If there is an x I'd like to change that into a 10. I am having trouble doing this! I have seen other questions that are somewhat similar and they all use regex. Like I said, I'd prefer to not use regex, but if need be...

```
    <h1>Problem #3:</h1>

    <form name= "form">
        <input id= "input" name= "isbn" type="number" placeholder="Enter your ISBN-10" min="0" />
        <input id= "button" type="button" name="Validate" value="Validate" />
    </form>

    <div id="validISBN">
        Valid ISBN
    </div>
    <div id="invalidISBN">
        Invalid ISBN
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            alert("Welcome to ISBN Validator!");
            //Add the event listener for the validate button here
            //Look at toggling the CSS display property based on the result
            $("#button").click(function(){
                checker(document.form.isbn.value);
            });
        });
var checker = function(isbn){
    isbn = isbn.toString().split('');
    if (isbn[9] == 'x'|| isbn[9] == 'X') {
        isbn[9] = 10;
    }
    if (isbn.length !== 10) {
        alert("invalid ISBN!" + isbn.length); 
    }
    else{
        var sum = 0;
        for (var x=10; x>0; x--){
            sum += x*isbn[10-x];
        }
        alert("FINAL!!" + sum%11);
    }
}
```

Input: 0375726721
Output: FINAL!!0
:Works

Input:067978330X
Expected Output: FINAL!!0
Actual Output: Invalid ISBN!0
:Does not work!

Comment: post some input and expected output

Comment: You are checking lower case 'x' instead of uppercase 'X'. Please cross check.

Comment: same result either way

Comment: im not familiar with character arrays but if i get it right you change the x into 10 right? so being that it has 9 characters + "10" wont it have 11 characters now which makes it invalid for this condition? isbn.length !== 10

Comment: @mikeandike : Changing the letter x to uppercase 'X' giving the same expected result what you want. Just change "if (isbn[9] == 'x')" to "if (isbn[9] == 'X')" .

Comment: But there are still only 10 elements in the array, therefore making the array length still 10. At least I think....

Comment: So you want array length to be 9 when it has 'X' appended?

Comment: I believe the issue has to do with the 2nd line, because the output seems to indicate that the length of the isbn is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isbn = '074759582x';

if (!/^\d{9}(\d|x)$/i.test(isbn)) // validation with regexp
    alert('Invalid ISBN');
else {
   var arr = isbn.split('');
   arr[9] = arr[9].toLowerCase() == 'x' ? 10 : arr[9]; // replacement of x by 10

   // below is your summation, just performed in another way. 
   var total = arr.map(function(el, index, arr) {
      return (index + 1) * arr[10 - index - 1];
   }).reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b;});

   alert(total % 11);
}
```

Done

Answer (score 0):

## Problem #3:

```
<form name= "form">
    <input id= "input" name= "isbn" type="number" placeholder="Enter your ISBN-10" min="0" />
    <input id= "button" type="button" name="Validate" value="Validate" onclick = "checker()" />
</form>

<div id="validISBN">
    Valid ISBN
</div>
<div id="invalidISBN">
    Invalid ISBN
</div>

<script>
     function checker () {            
         isbn = document.form.isbn.value;
        isbn = isbn.toString().split('');
        if (isbn[9] == 'x' || isbn[9] == 'X') {
            isbn[9] = 10;
        }
        if (isbn.length !== 10) {
            alert("invalid ISBN!" + isbn.length);
        }
        else {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var x = 10; x > 0; x--) {
                sum += x * isbn[10 - x];
            }
            alert("FINAL!!" + sum % 11);
        }
    }
     </script>
```

Comment: Code has been changed to include both uppercase and lowercase situations. Still no success.

Comment: Can you please hard code isbn and try. I think there is issue how you call the function.                                                        function checker(isbn){
isbn = "067978330X"

Comment: As you are getting output as ‘Invalid ISBN!0 ‘. There is an issue how you pass the parameter. Please hard code the text inside script and check.

Comment: please copy the same content and try

Answer (score 0):

```
var isbn = '074759582x';
```

Split the string into characters using `split`. Apply map to grab the `x` and convert it to 10 if necessary. Then map each character to a number

```
array = isbn
    .split('') 
    .map(function(char, i) { 
        return i === 9 && char.toLowerCase() === 'x' ? 10 : char;
    })
    .map(Number)
;
```

The ISBN is valid if it's of length 10, and there are no NaNs in it.

```
valid = array.length === 10 && !array.some(isNaN);
```

Checksum uses reduce, as in another answer:

```
sum = array.reduce(function(result, v, i) {
    return result + (10-i) * v;
}, 0) % 11;
```